# Converting VB Format() to PHP

Tags: php, vbscript, string-formatting

I'm trying to convert a encrypt/decrypt function from VB to PHP, but I'm having problems with this part:

```
Format＄(Hex＄(AscSrc), ″@@″)`
```

Is there a way to convert that to PHP? I couldn't find how to convert the @ symbol.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar to VB, but it looks like its doing a `str_pad(dechex(ord($AscSrc[0])), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);` or simply `bin2hex($AscSrc[0]);`.

Maybe you can optimize this code, sinse PHP has the `bin2hex();` function which instantly convert the entire string into a sequence of 2-digit hexadecimals. You can put a space between them with `preg_replace('/../' '\0 ', bin2hex($AscSrc));` if thats the case.